# Selenium con python dar click a todos los radiobutton de una pagina

Tags: python, selenium, radiobutton

Quiero darle click a todos los radiobutton de una pagina que me encuentro testeando, el problema es que son cerca de 200 radios.

**El test es el siguiente:**

1. Login en el aplicativo.
2. Se carga el website, con los radios a probar.
3. Selecciono un radiobutton e ingreso un id en una caja de texto y le doy click a consultar
4. En base al radio seleccionado, el front muestra información.

Soy algo novato en selenium, pero tengo algo como esto:

```py
    def test_consulta_reporte(self):
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="RDB_report_1"]').click()
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('txtID').send_keys('1234')
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('btnCON').click()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
```

El problema es que no es una función genérica, y debería copiar la misma modificando el elemento a testear **RDB_report_1**.

Los radios tienen un identificativo único que empieza con RDB_report_#.
**Donde** el **#** es carácter que varia, ya que el siguiente reporte es RDB_report_2.

Me gustaría si es posible iterar ese numero en la función que tengo hecha o alguna forma mas eficiente.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer un bucle y parametrizar la función si siempre lleva el mismo patron:

```
def checkTodosRadioButtons(self):
    for i in range(0,200):
        test_consulta_reporte(i)

def test_consulta_reporte(self, radioButtonNum):
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="RDB_report_' + str(radioButtonNum)+'"]').click()
    self.driver.find_element_by_id('txtID').send_keys('1234')
    self.driver.find_element_by_id('btnCON').click()
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
```